How to Prevent Values Changed Through Inspect Element From Setting a Bool
I am using EditContext.IsModified() to set a bool that tracks if there are any unsaved changes on the page. When altering values through Inspect Element, unsaved changes are detected and the bool is set.
Is there a workaround to prevent changes through the inspector from setting the bool? Is there a better way to approach tracking unsaved changes in an EditForm?

Why do you need to handle such a use case? DevTools is intended for developer and when people use it, they should expect unusual behaviors and in no way us developers should worry about it.

There's a better way.
The EditContext doesn't track the modification state of the model against the original.  It just tracks change.  Change a property to a new value and then back to the original: EditContext will maintain this as modified.
There's a Question and Answer on the subject here that I wrote:  Managing State and Preventing Blazor Navigation in an Edit Form
And a Repo [of mine] for an edit state tracker component here: https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.EditStateTracker
